# Running two kernel threads. How to achieve it?

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have written a kernel module to run two thread. But it keeps crashing. I think the init function seems to have the problem. Here's the init function

```
 int __init ksocket_init(void)
 {
    kthread = kmalloc(sizeof(struct kthread_t), GFP_KERNEL);
    memset(kthread, 0, sizeof(struct kthread_t));

    /* start kernel thread */
    kthread->thread = kthread_run((void *)ksocket_start, NULL, MODULE_NAME);
    kthread_server->thread = kthread_run((void *)ksocket_start_server, NULL, MODULE_NAME);

    if (IS_ERR(kthread->thread) || IS_ERR(kthread_server->thread)) {
            printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": unable to start kernel thread\n");

            kfree(kthread);
            kthread = NULL;

            kfree(kthread_server);
            kthread = NULL;

            return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whats wrong with it? I familiar with multithreading at application level. But, I don't have sufficient knowledge of kernel threads. Any help is appreciated.

ANSWER :

I was using unallocated kthread_server variable.

NEW PROBLEM:

But, now I'm unable to unload the module. Here's the exit function.

```
void __exit ksocket_exit(void)
{
int err;
struct mutex mutex_ks;

mutex_init(&mutex_ks);
if (kthread->thread==NULL)
        printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": no kernel thread to kill\n");
else
{
        mutex_lock(&mutex_ks);
        err = kthread_stop(kthread->thread);
        mutex_unlock(&mutex_ks);

        /* wait for kernel thread to die */
        if (err < 0)
                printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": unknown error %d while trying to terminate kernel thread\n",-err);
        else
        {
                while (kthread->running == 1)
                        msleep_interruptible(10);
                printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": succesfully killed kernel thread!\n");
        }
}

/* free allocated resources before exit */
if (kthread->sock_local != NULL)
{
        sock_release(kthread->sock_local);
        kthread->sock_local = NULL;
}

kfree(kthread);
kthread = NULL;

if (kthread_server->thread==NULL)
        printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": no kernel thread to kill\n");
else
{
            mutex_lock(&mutex_ks);
        err = kthread_stop(kthread_server->thread);
        mutex_unlock(&mutex_ks);

        /* wait for kernel thread to die */
        if (err < 0)
                printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": unknown error %d while trying to terminate kernel thread\n",-err);
        else
        {
                while (kthread_server->running == 1)
                        msleep_interruptible(10);
                printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": succesfully killed kernel thread!\n");
        }
}

/* free allocated resources before exit */
if (kthread_server->sock != NULL)
{
        sock_release(kthread_server->sock);
        kthread_server->sock = NULL;
}

kfree(kthread_server);
kthread_server = NULL;

printk(KERN_INFO MODULE_NAME": module unloaded\n");
}
```

Can anyone figure out problem with this?

Comment: You don't really need to `kmalloc` just to keep two pointers. Why not, just keep a normal variable? Also, your `ksocket_start` and `ksocket_start_server` functions must be of the correct type, in which case you don't need a cast to `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using unallocated memory under `kthread_server`. Allocate just as `kthread` variable.